# Can't store user identity Yii2

Tags: yii2, identity

When my user logs in and passes the validation without errors I have a `login` function inside my `LoginForm.php`, which must save the user in the session. My function looks like this:

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $email = $this->email;
            $user = $this::find()->where(['email' => $email])->asArray()->one();
            $user['password'] = '_';
            Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And inside of `SiteController` I have this function:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->login()) {
            $this->redirect(['users/profile']);
        }

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

The problem is in my `login` function, because when I comment the `&& $model->login()` part in my if statement the error goes away.

Here is the error which I'm getting:

```
Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must be an instance of yii\web\IdentityInterface, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii_grig\models\LoginForm.php on line 72
```

The error is this line in my `login` function - `Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user);`.

This is how my `models/User.php` file looks like:

```
<?

namespace app\models;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements  \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this and save user in the session?

Comment: you need to simply remove the `->asArray()` call in your login method. also remove this line `$user['password'] = '_';`

Comment: I am still getting the same error after removing the `->asArray()` and commenting `$user['password'] = '_';`

Comment: fair enough .. can you post `LoginForm::find()` method?

Comment: I don't have a `find` method in `LoginForm`

Comment: you are calling `$this::find()` here: `$user = $this::find()->where(['email' => $email])->asArray()->one()` this probably needs to be `User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->->one()`

Comment: Now I have error saying `Unable to find 'app\models\User' in file: C:\xampp\htdocs\yii_grig/models/User.php. Namespace missing?`. I have added my `models\User.php` file in the question so you can take a look. I also added `use app\models\User;` in `LoginForm`.

Comment: looks fine tho.. maybe it's because of the short opening tag? `<?` instead of `<?php`

Comment: Back to the same error xD. Anyway i'll let you know what was wrong when I solve the problem.

Comment: use `self::find()` instead and you need to pass the user object so remove asArray()

Comment: Delete, asArray() and You can also unset() the password, If you want to (not necessary)

Comment: @Grigory Volkov That happens because you trying to find a user without to get an instance of user model, try this: `$user = User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->one();` You will have a model which inherit an User Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to your models LoginForm.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

and this to your models User.php

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }
    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }
    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }
        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Finds user by verification email token
     *
     * @param string $token verify email token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByVerificationToken($token) {
        return static::findOne([
            'verification_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }
    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }
    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }
    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }
    public function generateEmailVerificationToken()
    {
        $this->verification_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }
    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }

    public function getUserProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::className(), ['id' => 'user_profile_id']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how should be:

```
use common\models\User;

...

/**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {

            $user = $this->getUser();
            if($user){
                if($user->status === User::STATUS_ACTIVE){
                    return Yii::$app->user->login($user, $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0); //set session
                 }
                 //any other logic
            }
            return false;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByEmail($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
```

Hope it helps.